# How can I add a new field from config inside hook_update_N?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, configuration

I have to add taxonomy by php code. Taxonomy has to got 2 fields. I added new function to test_taxonomy.install, and it seems to work:

```
function taxonomy_update_8805() {

    $config_path = 'modules/feature/test_taxonomy/config/update/';
    $source = new FileStorage($config_path);

    \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_vocabulary')
        ->create($source->read('taxonomy.vocabulary.regulation'))
        ->save();
}
```

Added new vocabulary to taxonomy.

Content of file:

```
langcode: pl
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - test_remote_vocabulary
third_party_settings:
  test_remote_vocabulary:
    is_remote: 0
name: 'Test'
vid: regulation
description: 'Test desc'
hierarchy: 0
weight: 0
```

The problematic part is when i try to add fields to the vocabulary.
I created 2 files

field.storage.taxonomy_term.field_regulation_test.yml

```
langcode: pl
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - taxonomy
    - text
id: taxonomy_term.regulation.test
field_name: test_field
entity_type: taxonomy_term
type: text_long
settings: {  }
module: text
locked: false
cardinality: 1
translatable: true
indexes: {  }
persist_with_no_fields: false
custom_storage: false
```

field.field.taxonomy_term.field_regulation_test.yml

```
langcode: pl
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - field.storage.taxonomy_term.field_regulation_test
    - taxonomy.vocabulary.regulation
id: taxonomy_term.regulation.test
field_name: test_content
entity_type: taxonomy_term
bundle: regulation
label: TEST
description: 'Tekst test'
required: true
translatable: false
default_value: {  }
default_value_callback: ''
settings: {  }
field_type: text_long
```

But i am not sure how can i load them in update_xxx function.

EDIT:
I tried

```
    \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
        ->create($source->read('field.storage.taxonomy_term.field_regulation_abo'))
        ->save();
        
    \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
        ->create($source->read('field.field.taxonomy_term.field_regulation_abo'))
        ->save();
```

but i'm getting *Missing bundle for entity type taxonomy_term* while trying to update module

Comment: Uh, seems I misunderstood the problem in my answer below. Thought you wanted to create terms, after some fields were added to the terms. But you seem to try to create a vocabulary and fields from hook_update_N. Why's that? Why don't you create it from config?

Comment: It is requied from client. We have to update module and add requieded vocabulary with fields. I decided not to use file like shown above, and add fields programatically, using Naveed Quadri answer from [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/139101/create-a-taxonomy-and-attach-a-field-to-it-programatically)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can't create content before the relying config has been imported. That's a [classic Drupal 8 paradox](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2901418) which has just recently been solved by a new hook: [`hook_deploy_NAME(&$sandbox)`](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/4365).

Update to the latest Drush and from now on run `drush deploy` as part of your deployment routine, which replaces the old `drush updb && drush cim` routine. Then create a new file in your module: `MYMODULE.deploy.php`. In there implement `MYMODULE_deploy_NAME(&$sandbox)` where `NAME` can be any unique name (or an incrementing number as well). And use this hook to create the terms, same as in the `hook_update_N(&$sandbox)` in your question.

`drush deploy` will ensure that this hook will be picked up at the very last in the deployment routine, after the relying config has been created from configuration import.

Comment: Seems there is no api doc page for this new hook yet.

Comment: https://www.drush.org/latest/deploycommand/